# How to enable/ disable "Automatic Reference Counting"?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.2

Using Xcode 4.2, how can one enable/disable  "Automatic Reference Counting"?

**ANSWERED** Under Build Settings, flip "yes" and "no" depending whether you want ARC enabled.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you enable ARC project-wide in Xcode 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476692/how-do-you-enable-arc-project-wide-in-xcode-4-2)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Globally:

Go to "Build Settings", look for "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language". Set the field
"Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" to "No".

[image]

For individual files:

Go to "Build Phases", select the file, double-click the "Compiler Flags" column and put
"-fno-objc-arc" in it.

Comment: I will, but note that ARC is not available on the Snow Leopard OSX (10.6) version of XCode 4.2

Comment: Nice answer, but you'll have a wizard's help if you go [Edit/Refactor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7759972/111307)

Answer (score 8):

To enable ARC per-file, you can also set your "Compiler Flags" under "Build Phases" to `-fobjc-arc`. Make sure your compiler is set to `Apple LLVM compiler 4.x` and **not** `LLVM GCC 4.2`.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 4.6 this property has now changed to CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC

[image: XCode 4.6 enabling Obj-C Automatic Reference Counting property]