# ARC convert for before iOS 5 SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

i have already developed a project upto iOS 4 compatible.
my question is now i want non-ARC to ARC enable project which should work on lates iOS 6 version.

Comment: Non-ARC projects also will work in the IOS 6

Comment: If you ARC-convert your project with the tools in xcode, it should still work in iOS 4.

Comment: See this link it will guide you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476692/how-do-you-enable-arc-project-wide-in-xcode-4-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your project to ARC using convert to arc tool of Xcode. Check below screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I know, ARC is just a Xcode compiler feature, it automatically analysis your code and insert memory release statements. It's per file instead of per project. It could be turn on/off by giving certain compile parameter. So you don't have to convert your existing code to ARC, it doesn't matter for iOS 6.