# How to change to use ARC from nonARC project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an project in nonARC mode. How to change it to ARC mode without create new project?

Is there any auto convert method, library or way? 
I also want auto delete release,autorelease and change some text(retain -> strong,...)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476692/how-do-you-enable-arc-project-wide-in-xcode-4-2?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This screen shot will help you

[image]

Read this [DaveOnCode](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/24/migration-to-arc-automatic-reference-counting-using-xcode-4-2-refactor/) and [Migrating your code to Objective-C ARC](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/).